# Residue field of finite extension of p adic numbers is a finite field.

Tags: finite-fields, local-field

Let $p$ be a prime and $\mathbb{Z}_p=\{a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+\cdots: 0\leq a_i<p-1\}$ ring of $p$ adic integers and $\mathbb{Q}_p$ be fraction field of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

We have valuation on $\mathbb{Q}_p$ given by $v_p(x)=n\in \mathbb{Z}$ where $x$ is unique representation $x=a_np^n+a_{n+1}p^{n+1}+\cdots$.

We see that $\mathcal{O}=\{x: v_p(x)\geq 0\}=\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a valuation ring wih unique non zero prime ideal $\mathfrak{m}=\{x:v_p(x)\geq 1\}=p\mathbb{Z}_p$ with residue field $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}=\mathbb{Z}_p/p\mathbb{Z}_p\cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. We can  have any valuation on $K$, but to be compatible with field extension criterion, we consider the valuation given by $v_K(x)=\frac{1}{n}v_p(N_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p}(x))$ where $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p}(x)$ is product of conjugates of $x$ under embeddings of $K$ in seperable closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

For this we have $\mathcal{O}_K=\{x: v_K(x)\geq 0\}$ and $\mathfrak{m}_K=\{x:V_K(x)\geq 1\}$.

Can we say that $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}_K$ is also a finite field just like $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}$ with out using anything else not mentioned here??

Comment: Well, for startes the ring of integers $\Bbb{Z}_p$ of the $p$-adic field $\Bbb{Q}_p$ is local with maximal ideal $p\Bbb{Z}_p$. What are your thoughts on the problem so far?

Comment: @Servaes In case of field of p adic numbers residue field is the field with p elements... could not generalise this for the case of finite extensions..

Comment: If $K$ is a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$, then its ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a finite extension of $\Bbb{Z}_p$. What does that tell you about the residue fields?

Comment: @Servaes What do you mean by finite extension of rings,,

Comment: What happens is that $\mathfrak{m}_K$ is a f.g. free $\Bbb{Z}_p$-module. And $p\mathcal{O}_K\subseteq \mathfrak{m}_K$. Does that help?

Comment: By the way, you should define $$\mathfrak{m}_K=\{x: v_K(x)>0\}.$$ If $K$ is a ramified extension $v_K$ will take fractional values. For example, you could have $K=\Bbb{Q}_p(\sqrt p)$ when $v_K(\sqrt p)=1/2$.

Comment: Welcome to master... I am not able to see that $\mathfrak{m}_K$ is free $\mathbb{Z}_p$ module.. I can see that $p\mathcal{O}_K\subset \mathfrak{m}_K$. Let $a\in \mathcal{O}_K$ then $v_K(a)\geq0$ and $v_K(pa)=v_K(p)+v_K(a)=1+v_K(a)>0$.. @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Oops I should have said that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a free $\Bbb{Z}_p$-module. If you can show that is finitely generated, then the rest is easy, because it is surely torsion free and over a PID f.g.+torsion free $\implies$ free.

Comment: Suppose we have $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}_p\oplus\cdots\oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$. We have $p\mathcal{O}_K\subset \mathfrak{m}_K$ i.e., $p\mathbb{Z}_p\oplus p\mathbb{Z}_p+\cdots+p\mathbb{Z}_p\subset \mathfrak{m}_K$ then $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}_K\subset (\mathbb{Z}_p\oplus\cdots\oplus \mathbb{Z}_p)/p\mathbb{Z}_p\oplus\cdots\oplus p\mathbb{Z}_p=\bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_p/p\mathbb{Z}_p=\bigoplus \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. So, $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}_K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ of degree atmost $n$ where $[K:\mathbb{Q}_p]=n$ @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: That's about right. But it may be that $\mathfrak{m}_K$ properly contains $p\mathcal{O}$. So, instead, I would say that there is a surjective homomorphism from $\mathcal{O}\simeq \Bbb{Z}_p^n$ **onto** $\mathcal{O}_k/\mathfrak{m}_K$ such that the kernel of this mapping contains $p\mathcal{O}_K$, and therefore $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}_K$ is a finite field of extension degree $\le n$ over the prime field.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thank you. Which way do you think is a better way of introducing local fields? Defining $\mathbb{Z}_p$, its field of fractions $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and its finite extensions or Take any Discrete valuation ring and its field of fractions and see if it is complete with finite residue field

Comment: I don't know. I'm not an expert on that. You can ask Lubin or Mariano. Or,... (many number theorists and/or algebraic geometers here know a lot about local fields).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok sir