# Show that $U/M$ is a finite field.

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

Let $U$ be a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra and let $M$ be the maximal ideal of $U$, where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers.

> Is $U/M$ a finite field ? If no, then what is the best possible structure on $U/M$ ?

In [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57515/a-finitely-generated-mathbbz-algebra-that-is-a-field-has-to-be-finite), the analogous question has been answered, the answer by @Daniel Litt, was easy to understand. However unlike $\mathbb{Z}$, the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is not Jacobson ring and hence inverse-image of the maximal ideal $M$ of $U$ under the ring homomorphism $f: \mathbb{Z}_p\to U$ may not (to check ?) be maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. This creates problem.

In otherwords, if the inverse image $f^{-1}(M)$ of the maximal ideal $M$ of $U$ becomes maximal then $\mathbb{Z}_p/f^{-1}(M)$ would be a finite field of characteristic $p$. In that case, since $U$ is finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, we get that  $U/M$ is a finite extension of the finite field $\mathbb{Z}_p/f^{-1}(M)$. Therefore $U/M$ is a finite field of prime characteristic.

So the question is-

how to make sure that the inverse image $f^{-1}(M)$ of the maximal ideal $M$ of $U$ becomes maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_p$  ?

Are there other way to answer the first question ?

For example,if $k$ is a field, then by Zariski Lemma, any finitely generated $k$-algebra $R$ and maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq R$, we have that $R/\mathfrak{m}$ is a finite field extension of $k$. Unfortunately in our case it is $\mathbb{Z}_p$  which is an integral domain but not field.

Thanks

**Edit:** Following answer shows if we assume $U$ to be $\text{finite}$ $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra instead of just $\text{finitely generated}$ $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra, then we are done.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra with infinite residue field. It’s not a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module. If $U$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra which is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module, then by Nakayama $pU$ isn’t equal to $U$ and is thus a proper ideal of $U$. Then $U/pU$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{F}_p$ module so is finite, so every residue field of $U$ where $p$ isn’t invertible is finite. If $I$ is a maximal ideal of $U$ where $p$ is invertible, then $\mathbb{Q}_p \rightarrow U/I$ is injective so $U$ can’t be a finitely generated module.

Comment: @Mindlack,  residue field of every non-Archimedian field is finite. why residue field of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is infinite ? Isn't it finite ?

Comment: @Mindlack, Further every $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra is also $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module. So I didn't understand your 2nd sentence

Comment: @Why Finitely generated *as a module* and finitely generated *as an algebra* are not the same. A very similar situation is that $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ is finitely generated as a $\Bbb{Z}$-algebra, but not as a $\Bbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: @SerVaes, Thank  you very much

Comment: @Why: I meant (although I’ll admit my wording wasn’t the best) that the quotient of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ by its (only) ideal is $\mathbb{Q}_p$ which is infinite. Note that the residue field (in the usual meaning) of a complete non-Archimedian field has of course no reason to be finite – think of $k((t))$ or $\mathbb{C}_p$.

Comment: @Mindlack, It is alright

Comment: @Mindlack, I think there is difference in the definition of residue field in between you and me. I am defining the residue field obtained from ring of integers modulo its maximal ideal. So in that sense the ring of integers of $k((t))$ is the ring of formal power series $k[[t]]$  and its maximal ideal is $(t)$. Hence the residue field of $k((t))$ is $k[[t]]/(t) \cong k$, which is finite. Am I right ?

Comment: @Mindlack, anyway. In your very first comment, you assumed $p$ in $pU$ to be non-invertible. Can you please why it is required to non-invertible ?  I couldn't understand it. Please explain

Comment: @Why: about $k((t))$ – it’s a complete non-Archimedean field for *any* field $k$, in particular for any infinite field $k$ (your definition in the correct one, as long as $k((t))$ is endowed with its most obvious absolute value and not something else entirely). Similarly, the residue field of $\mathbb{C}_p$ for the $p$-adic absolute value is $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ so infinite. Or the residue field of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ *for the trivial absolute value* (*not* the $p$-adic one) is tautologically $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: @Why: re my first comment. Basically I’m saying what Servaes says in their answer (only they’re doing it better). Let $I$ be a maximal ideal of $U$ (which is assume to be a $\mathbb{Z}_p$ module of finite type and a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra). Then $U/I$ is a field and a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module of finite type. If $p \notin I$, then $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (not a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module of finite type) injects into $U/I$, a contradiction. Thus $p \in I$, so that $U/I$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{F}_p$-module hence is finite.

Comment: @Mindlack, Thank you very much.I asked this because often in p-adic number theory we require to `invert`  the prime $p$. I just wanted to understand the general philosophy why the word `invert` is so important. However thank you very much, I got it for the current situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the claim you are trying to prove is somewhat ambiguous or misleading:

> Let $U$ be a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra and let $M$ be **the** maximal ideal of $U$, where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers.
> Show that $U/M$ is a finite field of characteristic prime, $p$ say.

In general a finitely generated $\Bbb{Z}_p$-algebra can have more than one maximal ideal, so it is unclear what *'the'* maximal ideal of $U$ should be.

Next note that $U:=\Bbb{Q}_p$ is a finitely generated $\Bbb{Z}_p$-algebra because $\Bbb{Q}_p\cong\Bbb{Z}_p[X]/(pX-1)$. Its maximal ideal is $M=0$, but clearly $U/M\cong\Bbb{Q}_p$ is not a finite field of prime characteristic.

---

If you require $U$ to be a finitely generated $\Bbb{Z}_p$*-module* then indeed $U/M$ is a finite field for *every* maximal ideal $M\subset U$. In this case $U/M$ is finitely generated as a $\Bbb{Z}_p/(M\cap\Bbb{Z}_p)$*-module*, where $M\cap\Bbb{Z}_p\subset\Bbb{Z}_p$ is a prime ideal of $\Bbb{Z}_p$. Because $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is local its only prime ideals are $0$ and $p\Bbb{Z}_p$, but if $M\cap\Bbb{Z}_p=0$ then $U/M$ contains $\Bbb{Z}_p$ as a subring, and hence also $\Bbb{Q}_p$, which is not finitely generated as a $\Bbb{Z}_p$-module, a contradiction. Hence $M\cap\Bbb{Z}_p=p\Bbb{Z}_p$, and from here your argument goes through.

Comment: First of all, $0$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. You didn't include it

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p$  has two prime ideals $0$ and $(p)$. we have kick out the possibility  to be $0$

Comment: @Why I think I've answered this question before... currently trying to find the duplicate.

Comment: ok, if you get it then attach the link

Comment: @Why I think I had my comments under [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071865/residue-field-of-finite-extension-of-p-adic-numbers-is-a-finite-field) in mind, which is not quite the same, but similar. Anyway it seems the claim you want to prove is false, if I have understood correctly. See my revised answer.

Comment: Ok, let me study

Comment: So what condition on $U$ does give assertive answer ? If it has no positive answer, what is best possible structure on $U/M$  ?

Comment: Requiring $U$ to be finitely generated as a $\Bbb{Z}_p$-module will give you an affirmative answer. I have included an argument for this.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally, after assuming $U$ to be finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module, do we further need $U$ to be finite $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra assumption ?

Comment: Just an update. If we assume $U$ to be `finite` $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra instead of just `finitely generated` $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra, then by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_algebra) $U$ will automatically be finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module. Can you verify please ?

Comment: What do you mean by a *'finite'* $\Bbb{Z}_p$-algebra? That is usually taken to mean *'finitely generated'*, but do you literally mean *'with finitely many elements'*?

Comment: Please see the bottom part of [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_algebra)

Comment: Yes, by that definition, if $U$ is a finite $\Bbb{Z}_p$-algebra then $U$ is automatically a finitely generated $\Bbb{Z}_p$-module. It seems I'm used to different terminology.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. However, as you said above, suppose $U$ is a local $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra with 'finitely many elements'. Then I think we don't need any further assumption in order to get affirmative answer. Am I right?

Comment: You don't even need to assume $U$ local; if $U$ has finitely many elements, then so does $U/M$ for any maximal ideal $M\subset U$ and hence $U/M$ is a finite field.

Comment: ahh. It was simple.Thank you very much